# SQL Server Stored Procedure - Generate Where clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have three parameters `@startDate`, `@endDate`, `@name`. The query I need to create a query that works like this.

- If `@startDate` is not empty, `WHERE @startDate <= time`
- If `@endDate` is not empty, add `WHERE @endDate >= time`
- If `@name` is not empty, add `WHERE name LIKE @name`

That's what I want to do.... and this is the crappy code I've written.

```
ALTER blahblah...
    @startDate varchar(10),
    @endDate varchar(10),
    @name varchar(7)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM st.TB_RETENTION
WHERE  
    CASE WHEN @startDate != '' THEN @startDate <= time AND 
    CASE WHEN @endDate != '' THEN @endDate >= time AND
    CASE WHEN @GameCode != '' THEN name LIKE @name
END
```

I think I'm quite close... but not sure how to add AND condition... Any advice for me? :(

Comment: To the extent I know....there is no 'end' to your case...add end   and check your procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually almost got it correct in your initial description:

```
where (@startDate is null or @startDate <= time)
  and (@endDate is null or @endDate >= time)
  and (@gameCode is null or name like @name)
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Gaaaaa, why was it to tricky to figure out that simple answer!?  I will accept your answer in 10 mins.